# I cannot reduce the screen brightness on my Acer Aspire 5742

Tags: drivers, 13.04, graphics, brightness

I cannot reduce the screen brightness in Ubuntu 13.04, my device is an Acer Aspire 5742. Ubuntu systems settings says the graphics driver is "Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2" but my laptop comes with "Intel HD Graphics". So I assume it's a problem with my graphic drivers. It would be great if some one could tell me how to uninstall my current driver and install the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and the right or left arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Installing graphics driver for Intel has become so easy.. You can use **Intel Linux Graphics Installer** to install/update your currentt graphics driver. After installation it will automatically scans your graphics device and install/update as needed.

Follow this instruction to install it:

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \

  sudo apt-key add -
  ```

  also

  ```
  wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \

  sudo apt-key add -

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
  ```

  or download it form [here for 32 bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/pool/13.04/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.2-0intel3_i386.deb) or [here for 64bit](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/pool/13.04/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.2-0intel3_amd64.deb)
- When installed successfully run this command from terminal:

  ```
  sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
  ```

  or open from the dash.
- Allow it to scan your graphics driver. Probably it will fix your graphics issue.

**To fix your brightness** you can try following trick:

Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

```
    $ sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_backup
    $ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then save the file and close. Finally execute following commands:

```
    $ sudo update-grub
    $ sudo reboot now
```

Hope after reboot your problem would be solved. Reply for further assistance..

<sub>[Source: 01.org](https://01.org/)</sub>